# using @background over two activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-annotations

Is it possible to create a background thread using andriodannotations thats starts in one activity and finish in another activity.

here is what i thought migh have worked

```
ActivityA
public static LoadingDialog LoadingScreen = new  LoadingDialog();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //.....
    LoadingScreen.CreateDialog(context);
} 


Background Class
public class LoadingDialog 
{
    private Dialog loader_dialog;
    @Background
    public void CreateDialog(Context mContext)
    {

        loader_dialog = new Dialog(mContext,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        loader_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
        loader_dialog.show();
    }
    public void Remove()
    {
        loader_dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

}

the dialog displays correctly but when I finish() activityA to start activityB the thread appears to be killed to and i get a black screen. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe a static class with application context might work? not sure though

Comment: You are totally misusing the `@Background` annotation. It is for creating background tasks, worker threads, for example some processing, or networking, etc. You are executing GUI related operations, these operations [must performed on the main (UI thread)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)!
If you start a new `Activity`, everything for the previous will disappear. If you want to show the dialog in the second, you have to open it again. But i suggest to redesign your UI, because this is not a good practice...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, probably the most useful comment i have had on SE. I just need to try and think of a design that suits a 3D game that s creating a surfaceview. its this creation of the surface view that stops me creating the new dialog in the second activity because i get a black screen for a few seconds while the surface view is created. i wonder if it is possible to create the surface view outside of the oncreate method so that the dialog gets shown immediately

Comment: Why do you have to show the dialog in the second `Activity`? The user clicks on it already in the first (i guess), that means the dialog should be dismissed.

Comment: because the second activity is where i create my glsurfaceview, any way i managed to fix the issue, i was parsing obj files in my renderer constructor when i should have been doing it in the onSurfaceCreate. this meant my constructor took a while to run everything and was for somereason stopping the dialog from displaying